# How to add django-editorjs-fields EditorJsTextField or EditorJsJSONField in html template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, editorjs

I am trying to add block style editor with [django-editorjs-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-editorjs-fields/). It work django admin fine but not working with template. I properly configure urls.py for static files. Here is my code sample.....
models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    content = EditorJsTextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'content': EditorJsWidget(plugins=["@editorjs/image", "@editorjs/header"])
        }
```

views.py

```
class PostFormView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:
https://prnt.sc/ytMX_522Y4zF

Not showing expected output. Show only normal textfield

Expected output:
https://prnt.sc/l0Uku9Xt-yNl

Answer (score 0):

for your field content if they return null. you need to add {{ form.media }} in bellow {{ form.as_p }} from your html file.

can be used as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ form.media }} <!-- new -->
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The details about this, you can be found at [documentation on github](https://github.com/2ik/django-editorjs-fields/blob/dev/example/blog/templates/blog/post_update.html)